# DataGridView ComboBox EditingControlShowing events

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I have a basic WinForms app with d DataGridView (named **dgvHardware**) control on it, bound to this control is this code:

```
    private void dgvHardware_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control is ComboBox)
        {
            ((ComboBox)e.Control).SelectionChangeCommitted -= new EventHandler(cboDgvHardware_SelectionChanged);
            ((ComboBox)e.Control).SelectionChangeCommitted += new EventHandler(cboDgvHardware_SelectionChanged);
        }
    }

    private void cboDgvHardware_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // string result is the selected text of the combo box
        // int row is the row index that the selected combo box lives
        string result = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString();
        // int row = ????
    }
```

Long story short, I need to be able to determine the row that the events are being fired on, in order to change other cells in the row based on the ComboBox selection.  The **result** in the second function returns correct values, for what it's worth.

Let me know if this is unclear or if you need any additonal information.

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [DataGridView.CurrentCell Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx) like this:

```
int row = dgvHardware.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
```

Comment: Bingo!  That was 99% correct, the DataGridView is named dgvHardware, so the fully correct line is:         

`int row = dgvHardware.CurrentCell.RowIndex;`

Answer (score 1):

You would be interested in the `dgvHardware.CurrentRow` which will give you acess to the entire row and you could navigate to different columns using `dgvHardware.CurrentRow.Cells[index or columnName]` and change the other cell values.